# When using Swift Mailer, how can I get control over the line breaks in the text/plain version of the message?

Tags: php, line-breaks, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift Mailer (version 4.1.7, which shouldn't matter for this topic), and I have a very basic question.

A "modern" email message typically repeats the content twice -- once in HTML, which most people read in their fancy browser-based mail reading apps, and once in plain text for those people using old or simple readers.  In Swift, it's easy to create both versions as follows:

```
$message->setBody($plaintextMessage, 'text/plain');
$message->addPart($htmlMessage, 'text/html');
```

The problem I'm having is that my plain text message (`$plaintextMessage` above) is being broken into lines while ignoring the newlines already present in `$plaintextMessage`.  This is appropriate if there are no newlines in the message.  Example, if I feed it this:

```
$plaintextMessage = 'This is a long-ish line, which we expect to be broken after about 72 characters.  It is a good behavior, appropriate in most instances.';
```

then I get this:

```
This is a long-ish line, which we expect to be broken after about 72 cha=
racters.  It is a good behavior, appropriate in most instances.
```

This is fine, expected, and so on.  *However*, if I do something like this:

```
$plaintextMessage = implode("\n", array('This is a series',
                                        'of short lines',
                                        'which should not be broken.',
                                        'They include their own',
                                        'newlines, which should be respected',
                                        'and preserved'));
```

then there are already perfectly fine newlines in the message.  Unfortunately, Swift seems to ignore them and outputs this:

```
This is a series
of short lines
which should not be broke=
n.
They include their own
newlines, which should be respecte=
d
and preserved
```

Of course, I realize that a modern mailer will remove the extra line breaks and equals signs, but the whole point of having a plain-text version of the message is that people using older mailers that don't understand this syntax should still be able to read the message without too much ugliness.

Is this a setting in Swift?  So far, the only thing I've thought to do is set the line length to a really high character count (longer than my message) as a workaround, thus preventing Swift from doing any kind of line breaks.  It seems to me, however, that Swift should be resetting its character count to zero every time it finds a line break already in the message.  Is it possible to induce this behavior?

Comment: why not removing all new lines then use your own function?

Answer (score 0):

It is not respecting the existing hard wraps in the text when calculating line length for soft-wrapping. That was changed with a [pull request on Swiftmailer 5.x last year](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/pull/627).